# how to decrease the number of mapper in hive while the file is bigger than block size?

Tags: hive, mapper

guys
  I have a table in hive which have more than 720 partitions，and in each partition there is more than 400 files and the file's average size is 1G.

Now I execute following SQL:
insert overwrite table test_abc  select * from  DEFAULT.abc  A WHERE A.P_HOUR ='2017042400'    ;

this partition (P_HOUR ='2017042400' )have 409 files. When I submit this sql ,I got following output

INFO  : Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
INFO  : number of splits:409

INFO : Submitting tokens for job: job_1482996444961_9384015

I google many doc to find how to decrease the number of mapper, lots of doc solved this problem when the file is small.
   I have tried the following set in beeline, but not work
---------------first time

```
set mapred.min.split.size =5000000000;
set mapred.max.split.size =10000000000;
set mapred.min.split.size.per.node=5000000000;
set mapred.min.split.size.per.rack=5000000000;
```

-----------------second time

```
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize =5000000000;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=10000000000;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.rack=5000000000;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.node=5000000000;
```

my hadoop version is 
Hadoop 2.7.2
Compiled by root on 11 Jul 2016 10:58:45
hive version is
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 1.3.0)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.3.0)

Comment: (1) `hive.execution.engine`? (2) `DEFAULT.abc` file format?

Comment: hive.execution.engine=mr  



SerDe Library:  org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe        
 InputFormat:  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat                  
 OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat

Comment: Can you confirm your execution engine. Is it tez or mr ?

Comment: execution engine is mr  
hive.execution.engine=mr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the setup in your post

```
set hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat=true;
```

> hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat
>    - Default Value: false
>    - Added In: Hive  0.6.0
>   Whether to combine small input files so that fewer mappers are spawned.

Comment: @lance - I suggests, please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: @SandeepSingh  Yes,That should be.Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

MRv2 uses `CombineInputFormat`, while Tez uses grouped splits to determine the Mapper. If your execution engine is `mr` and you would like to reduce Mappers use:

```
mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=xxxxx
```

If `maxSplitSize` is specified, then blocks on the same node are combined to a single split. Blocks that are left over are then combined with other blocks in the same rack. If `maxSplitSize` is not specified, then blocks from the same rack are combined in a single split; no attempt is made to create node-local splits. If the `maxSplitSize` is equal to the block size, then this class is similar to the default splitting behavior in Hadoop

This [link](https://hadoopjournal.wordpress.com/2015/06/13/set-mappers-in-pig-hive-and-mapreduce/) can be helpful to control Mapper in Hive if your execution engine is `mr`

If your execution engine is `tez` and you would lile to control Mappers then use:

```
set tez.grouping.max-size = XXXXXX;
```

Here is a good read [reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TEZ/How+initial+task+parallelism+works) for the parallelism in Hive for `tez` execution engine,